# Instal Epson XP-540 with Linux Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I Have an Epson XP-540 and Linux Ubuntu on my computer and need a driver ?? as they do not talk. can anyone assist. HBW

Comment: Check this out: https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/epson_xp_540.html

Comment: Get the drivers here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
sudo aptitude install printer-driver-escpr
```

and after that, this driver appeared: `EPSON XP-530 Series , Epson Inkjet Printer Driver (ESC/P-R) for Linux` — which seems to work fine, although I have an XP-540 not XP-530.

(Before that, I also installed `imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.20.x64.deb.tar.gz`, which I downloaded from here: `http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.20#ubuntu`, and I also: `sudo aptitude install lsb` — not sure which (if any) of these things were actually needed. They did not make the printer work.)